# How to calculate original amount before the discount?

Tags: percentages

I have an amount I want to receive: 350€

I know from the original request I will have to do a discount: 40%

What is the original request I have to ask?

```
350 = x - (x * 40%)
```

Where `x` = Original Request

Excuse me if this question is too naïve or already answered. Possible I am not doing the proper search.

Comment: Note that your equation is the same as $350=x-.4\times x=.6\times x$.  So you just need to divide by $.6$

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I've added an answer with your solution

Comment: Looks good (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [@lulu comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440615/how-to-calculate-original-amount-before-the-discount#comment9296878_4440615)

```
350 = x - 0.4x
350 = 1x - 0.4x
350 = (1 - 0.4)x
350 = 0.6x
350 / 0.6 = x

x = 583.3333
```